# Unable to add configurable product to shopping cart using soap api

Tags: configurable-product, api

I'm having some troubles adding configurable products to the shopping cart via shoppingCartProductAdd. Lets say that I have:

- a **Configurable** product with the **sku configurable-shirt**
- that has options **size** (optionId 92) and **color** (optionId 134)
- that has an **associated** (simple) product with option selection for the **size ExtraLarge** (selectionid 20) and for the **color Green** (selectionid 5)
- the **color Green** has a fixed price configured at **5eur**

As I understand, I should add the configurable-shirt to the shopping cart as follows:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:urn="urn:Magento">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <urn:shoppingCartProductAddRequestParam>
         <sessionId>91b24f514cfc125bac900a682586ecd0</sessionId>
         <quoteId>254</quoteId>
         <productsData>
            <complexObjectArray>
               <sku>configurable-shirt</sku>
               <qty>1.0</qty>
               <options>
                  <complexObjectArray>
                     <key>92</key> <!-- size -->
                     <value>20</value> <!-- ExtraLarge -->
                  </complexObjectArray>
                  <complexObjectArray>
                     <key>134</key> <!-- color -->
                     <value>5</value> <!-- Green -->
                  </complexObjectArray>
               </options>
            </complexObjectArray>
         </productsData>
         <store>default</store>
      </urn:shoppingCartProductAddRequestParam>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

But all I get is a response telling me to define the product options which, if you ask me, I just did in the soap message.

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <SOAP-ENV:Body>
      <SOAP-ENV:Fault>
         <faultcode>1022</faultcode>
         <faultstring>Please specify the product's option(s).</faultstring>
      </SOAP-ENV:Fault>
   </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

If I however use the **sku of the associated** simple product whis is configurable-shirt-Green-ExtraLarge the products is added to the shopping cart, but the **5eur price addition** to color green **is not added** to the products total sum.

The configurable product works as expected if I use the magento frontend.
I'm using 1.8.0.0

Comment: Were you able to resolve this? Please share.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found solution to this, but since Magento has missed this point in the default Soap functionality so had to create a custom module to over-ride the default wsdl of checkout in magento.

You can find my complete solution with the custom module-code at the below URL:
http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/829246/

Solution:
I checked what parameters do magento sent to product add function when configurable product is added to cart from front-end. 
The post parameters contained an array

[super_attribute] => Array( [92] => 248,  [175] => 249 )

But Magento do not include this element in the default WSDL and WSI xml file, which is located at path /rootfolder/app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/etc

```
"WSI.XML FILE"
<xsd:complexType name="shoppingCartProductEntity">
                <xsd:sequence>
                    <xsd:element name="product_id" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                    <xsd:element name="sku" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                    <xsd:element name="qty" type="xsd:double" minOccurs="0"/>
                    <xsd:element name="options" type="typens:associativeArray" minOccurs="0"/>
                    <xsd:element name="bundle_option" type="typens:associativeArray" minOccurs="0"/>
                    <xsd:element name="bundle_option_qty" type="typens:associativeArray" minOccurs="0"/>
                    <xsd:element name="links" type="typens:ArrayOfString" minOccurs="0"/>
                </xsd:sequence>
            </xsd:complexType>

"WSDL.XML FILE"
<complexType name="shoppingCartProductEntity">
                <all>
                    <element name="product_id" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                    <element name="sku" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                    <element name="qty" type="xsd:double" minOccurs="0"/>
                    <element name="options" type="typens:associativeArray" minOccurs="0"/>
                    <element name="bundle_option" type="typens:associativeArray" minOccurs="0"/>
                    <element name="bundle_option_qty" type="typens:associativeArray" minOccurs="0"/>
                    <element name="links" type="typens:ArrayOfString" minOccurs="0"/>
                </all>
            </complexType>
```

What i did is i over-ride the default “wsdl.xml” and “wsi.xml”, by creating a custom module and added the new element name “super_attribute” to the xml under my custom module etc folder.

```
"My module WSDL file"
<complexType name="shoppingCartProductEntity">
    <all>
        <element name="super_attribute" type="typens:associativeArray" minOccurs="0"/>
    </all>
</complexType>

"My Module WSI file"
<xsd:complexType name="shoppingCartProductEntity">
         <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="super_attribute" type="typens:associativeArray" minOccurs="0"/>
    </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
```

This will add this new element to the main wsdl and you can confirm it by running the following URL: http://yourhost.com/index.php/api/v2_soap/?wsdl and search for string like “shoppingCartProductEntity”

Now adding a product to cart using Magento’s Soap request, i added product to cart using below code

```
$product = array(
            'product_id' => 'product-id',
            'sku' => 'product-sku',
            'qty' => '1',
            'super_attribute' => array(
                0 => array(
                'key' => attribute-id,
                'value' => attribute-value
                ),
                1 => array(
                'key' => attribute-id,
                'value' => attribute-value
                )
            ),
            'bundle_option' => null,
            'bundle_option_qty' => null,
            'links' => null
        );
$productAdded = $soapObject->shoppingCartProductAdd($sessionId,$quoteId,array($product),'1');
```

By this the configurable product was added to cart.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Feel free to copy the solution on this site also. As sadly links can die.

Comment: Hi David, complete solution added :)

Comment: i have added super attribute  'super_attribute' => array(
                0 => array(
                'key' => 92,
                'value' => 10
                ),
                1 => array(
                'key' => 134,
                'value' => 3
                )
            ),  but the product is not added to cart.  kindly tell me how to add the option values.

Comment: @RahulTyagi Hi,i add your custom madule to magento and then try to add confugure able product to cart but it`s return me this message : please specify product option(s)

Comment: If you are changing wsdl, be sure wsdl caching is off. SoapClient(Mage::getBaseUrl() . 'index.php/api/v2_soap/?wsdl', array('cache_wsdl' => WSDL_CACHE_NONE));